# How to pass arguments in pytest to the parametrize decorator

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test case where the *parametrize* decorator uses an iterator (that receives two path files as arguments) which test their validity.

```
def iter_wb_results(expected_path, test_path):
    test_file = open(test_path, "r")
    ...

@pytest.mark.parametrize("first, second", iter_wb_results(EXPECTED_RESULTS_PATH, TEST_PATH), ids=repr)
def test_cell_compare(first, second):
    assert first == second, "No way"
```

The question is how do I pass arguments (the *EXPECTED_RESULTS_PATH, TEST_PATH*) to the iterator (*iter_wb_results*) from the command line?

Comment: Nope not a duplicate

Comment: Yes, duplicate. Would you like to have a constructive discussion now?